# How to check session variable exists from windows form applications

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application running on browser. With the help of a windows application running at the same time, can I check if any specific session variable exists or not?
Basically, I want to check the web application session variables from my windows application.
Is it possible?

Comment: Session is created for specified user (user has usually special session cookie that serves as key to server session storage). Windows application can know nothing about currently logged in user. Do you want to track session state for all users simultaneously ?

Comment: Can I track session state for all users simultaneously ?

Comment: If you want to store something that isn't actually session data, why store it in the session at all? I would argue that data you want to see outside of the web app session is not truly session data - it's just user data. And that could be stored in any database table you like, and accessible from anything that can query it.

Comment: Assuming that a user ID and a session start time are adequate, you can use the `Session_Start` event in the global asax to write that information to a database. The winforms app can then pick it up from there. That greatly increases coupling now though so pushing that to a message queue might be the better option.

Comment: I want clarify where you want to check: from computer where browser opened asp app or at server side?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but it is large undertaking and I hope you have a good reason for doing so (I couldn't think of any).

Anyway as there is no "get state for all users" in default session state provider - you have to implement it yourself. What you're probably using right now as session state provider is System.Web.SessionState.InProcSessionStateStore, which derives from SessionStateStoreProviderBase; what you need to do is implement your own session state store provider, that will derive from SessionStateStoreProviderBase as well.

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178589(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178589%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Then you can make method "get state for all users" on that provider, and expose that method through webservice that will communicate with your windows application. Needless to say this webservice should be secured as session state can contain sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do this.   The computer running the browser is not the same physical machine as the server.  The server stores the values.   The client has a magic session id that the server uses to figure out client requests.